# Where's moderator "Bryan Denny"?

Tags: discussion, moderators

Haven't seen him for a *great* while. Is he off for vacation or something else?

Answer (score 8):

You're right that Bryan isn't very visible on the site lately, but he's still actively moderating. Don't forget that many moderation actions are invisible to normal users (with less than 10k reputation): deleting posts or comments, removing posts from review queues, messaging or suspending users. Even the more visible actions (closing questions, editing, commenting on posts that need improvement) are not that noticeable unless you happen to see an affected post.

The rest of us are probably more noticeable because of the non-moderator things we do on the site: asking and answering questions. I don't think it's new that Bryan is the least active of us in that sense, but that doesn't mean he's stopped visiting the site or stopped moderating.

Comment: Well put! And confirmed :) Maybe worth mentioning some actions aren't even visible to users with 20k+ reputation (unless they happen to be moderators, too) :D

Comment: @Izzy Any proof? I can't find his activities (SE) network-wide

Comment: @iBug nothing that I can give to you. But I can assure you he's around.

Comment: @iBug we mods don't post screenshots from "mod land", sorry. Apart from that: what issue are you trying to solve that you need to know about Bryan? ;)

Comment: I apparently missed this question (over a year ago!). I'm still actively moderating in the background. And I am also on StackOverflow daily (being a programmer and all as well). Most of my moderation actions are not visible to normal users of this site.