# 2018 Community Moderator Election Results

Tags: discussion, election

Android Enthusiasts's [fifth moderator election](https://android.stackexchange.com/election/5) has come to a close, the votes have been tallied and the two new moderators are:

[image: Firelord] [image: beeshyams]

They'll be joining [the existing crew](https://android.stackexchange.com/users?tab=moderators) shortly—please thank them for volunteering, and share your assistance and advice with them as they learn the ropes!

Also, please join me in thanking Matthew Read and Dan Hulme who will be stepping down as moderator.

For details on how the voting played out, you can download the election results [here](https://android.stackexchange.com/election/5), or [view a summary report online](https://www.opavote.com/results/4867559245479936/0).

Comment: Thank you Matt and Dan for all of your hard work!

Comment: Best of luck, all!  It was impossible to make a bad choice in this election, almost too bad only 2 spots were up and not 3.

Answer (score 9):

I thank the community for trusting me with this privilege. I deeply respect that, and I would, to the extent possible and permissible, attempt to ensure that my actions as a Moderator contribute to the betterment of our community.

I'm, however, shocked to find three Moderators leaving their diamond privilege in a row. They are some of the most valuable veteran users we have. I've personally learned a lot from them, from their actions as a Moderator and equally from their inspiring high-quality answers.

I'd like to take this opportunity to thank them for serving this community as Moderators in keeping the site tidy and neat to the extent they could, and more so in its troubled times. I hope that they would continue to stay with us, visit us whenever they could, and contribute here with their expertise which we genuinely crave for. :-)

Comment: Welcome to the mod squad!

Comment: @Bryan Haven't seen you around on the main site for years (posting/editing/closing etc.) Would you ming coming to [this question](https://android.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2280/205764)?

Comment: @iBug I'm still around and actively moderating! There's a lot of moderation that happens behind the scenes and is not visible to other users.

Answer (score 9):

A sincere thanks to the community for reposing your trust and confidence in me to be a moderator.

Dan leaving us was known since he communicated his reasoning on Meta. It was an unpleasant surprise but  I fully respect his decisions.

Matthew leaving is a shocker coming out of the blue. At a personal level, I wouldn't have been an active member of this community without him guiding me out of (self created) mess.

As they say of Veterans *Old soldiers never die, they fade away* ; leaving behind their imprints and inspiring us to do better.

I wish both  veterans, the best and hope that they do not go off the radar and continue to help the community.

Comment: Welcome to the mod squad!

Comment: @BryanDenny : Thanks. Hope to gain from your guidance

Answer (score 6):

Congrats to the beloved guys, beeshyams and Firelord! You two have been super helpful since long ago, and we all believe that you are great candidates for this holy work of keeping our site clean and tidy!

Thank you for all your dedication towards helping the site grow!

Answer (score 0):

1.5 months after the election, [beeshyams](https://android.stackexchange.com/users/131553/beeshyams) no longer has a diamond.

The site now has **fewer** mods than before the election.

Comment: It is unfortunate but he had to leave for personal reasons. He was already on leave for the last two weeks.